# viewDidLoad multithreading issue

Tags: ios, json, multithreading

I have to make a separate api call that returns some JSON data for each movie that I want to get information about. I am trying to loop through the array of movie IDs and call populateAssetObject on each one of them in my viewDidLoad method.

If I go into debugging mode and step through the for loop, it will populate movies correctly with all 5 titles, but if I run it normally, my movies array is only the first 2 objects. I think this may be caused by some multithreading? I'm not really an expert in that area, does anyone know what my problem could be?

viewDidLoad:

```
_movies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *curr in assetIDs) {
    [self populateAssetObject:curr];
}
```

here is the populateAssetObject method

```
-(void)populateAssetObject:(NSString *)videoID {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[api url]", videoID];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:restURLString];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *contents = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    OVDAsset *newAsset = [[OVDAsset alloc] init];
    [newAsset setTitle:[contents valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [newAsset setDescription:[contents valueForKey:@"longDescription"]];

    [self.movies addObject:newAsset];
}
```

Comment: There is no multithreading taking place above. Can you log out the contents dictionary for every call, NSLog(@"contents %@", contents); Also, initialize the movies array like this, self.movies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: You didn't mention anything like this, but I'm wondering: are you determining that the items from the array aren't loading based on what you're seeing in a UITableView? The reason I ask is because, if I understand correctly, the data will be retrieved on a separate thread. (The OS takes care of this.) Thus, if you're looking at the results in the GUI, it may be that the view and its table view load before all the objects are in. If that's the case, you'll need some way of knowing when the last object is in. When the last object is in, you'll need to reload the table.

Comment: I added reloadData at the end of populateAssetObject and that seems to have fixed it, although I could have sworn I tried this before and it didn't. The contents do log the full 5 movies now, and I can see everything in the tableview. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: That is not the best approach. Since the above loop is being called synchronously, you can call reloadData after the for loop. Unless you are calling populateAssetObject in other places, your app will take a performance hit calling reloadData for each videoId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach has an important issue:

Your method `populateAssetObject:` is a *synchronous* method and it will access remote resources. This method will be executed on the *main* thread, and thus this blocks the UI.

That you invoke it in a loop, makes the situation only worse.

What you *really* would need is an *asynchronous* method which performs all that in a background thread, and a completion block which notifies the call-site when the whole operation is finished:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)();
- (void) populateAssetsWithURLs:(NSArray*) urls completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;
```

In your `viewDidLoad` you would then do this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self populateAssetsWithURLs:urls ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }];
}
```

The tricky part is to implement the method `populateAssetsWithURLs:completion:`.

A quick and dirty approach which look like this:

```
- (void) populateAssetsWithURLs:(NSArray*) urls
                     completion:(completion_t)completionHandler
{
    NSUInteger count = [urls count];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            [self synchronousPopulateAssetObject:urls[i]];
        }
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler();
        }
    });
}

- (void) synchronousPopulateAssetObject:(NSString*)url {
   ...
}
```

This approach has a few issues:

It blocks at least one thread (but likely more) just for waiting on the result. This approach is inefficient regarding system resources - but it may work.

#### Asynchronous Loop

A better approach would employ an asynchronous design. The tricky part with this approach is that you have a *list* of *asynchronous* tasks (`asynchronousPopulateAssetObject`), each one needs to be started asynchronously and the final result is only available asynchronously as well. Having a `for loop` is quite inappropriate for making a loop asynchronous.

Thus, you may imagine an API like this, which could be a Category of `NSArray`:

Category NSArray:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(id result);

-(void) forEachPerformTask:(task_t)task completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;
```

Note, that `task` is an asynchronous block of type `task_t`, having its own completion handler as a parameter:

```
typedef void (^task_t)(id input, completion_t);
```

The task will be asynchronously applied for each element in the array. When all elements have been processed, the client will be notified by calling the completion handler passed in method forEachPerformTask.

You can find a complete implementation and a short sample here on GitHub Gist: [transform_each.m](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/6155227).

Shortly, I'll edit my answer and demonstrate a much more elegant approach, which utilizes a helper library, especially suited to solve asynchronous patterns like this one.

But before that I will just demonstrate another approach utilizing `NSOperationQueue`:

#### NSOperationQueue

`NSOperationQueue` has the invaluable advantage that running and pending asynchronous tasks can be **cancelled**. In fact, an asynchronous solution which executes a list of operations which cannot be cancelled is an incomplete solution and likely not suitable at all in most scenarios.

Furthermore, `NSOperationQueue` can execute its tasks concurrently. The number of the occurrent tasks can be set with property `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.

There are a few variations when using a `NSOperationQueue` and the basic idea of the most simple one would be:

```
NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2;

for (NSString* url in urls) {
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self synchronousPopulateAssetObject:url];
    }];
}
```

Here, the operation queue is configured to run two tasks in parallel. An operation will be created using the convenient method `addOperationWithBlock:` which creates an `NSOperation` object on the fly from a block.

The tasks will be enqueued at at once in the for loop. This is different to the "dispatch approach" whose implementation is shown on Gist. In the the "dispatch approach" a new task will be enqueued only after the preceding one has been finished. This is quite friendly to system resources.

The disadvantage here is, that one cannot *asynchronously* determine when all the tasks have been finished. There is a "blocking" solution though, using method `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`. Since this method **blocks** the calling thread, and since we want an asynchronous method `populateAssetsWithURLs:completion:` we need to wrap the synchronous method into an asynchronous one as follows:

```
- (void) populateAssetsWithURLs:(NSArray*) urls
                     queue:(NSOperationQueue*)queue
                     completion:(completion_t)completionHandler
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        for (NSString* url in urls) {
            [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self synchronousPopulateAssetObject:url];
            }];
        }
        [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler();
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** the client provides the queue. This is because the client can send `cancelAllOperations` to the queue at any time to stop the execution of the pending and running tasks.

The disadvantage here is, that we need an extra thread which gets blocked just for the purpose to deliver the eventual result (which could be passed as a parameter in the completion handler).

Another disadvantage is when using the convenient method `addOperationWithBlock:` we don't have the opportunity to specify a completion handler for the asynchronous task.

And another disadvantage when using convenient method `addOperationWithBlock:` is that we don't get the `NSOperation` which would be required to setup *dependencies* to other `NSOperation` objects (see [Operation Dependencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW14) in the official documentation of NSOperation).

If we want to leverage the full power of `NSOperations` and `NSOperationQueue` we would have to be more elaborate. For example, having a completion handler which notifies the call-site when the operation queue has processed ALL its tasks, is doable - but it requires to setup *dependencies* and this requires an `NSOperation` **object** where we need a subclass, and need to execute the code what was formerly the simple asynchronous task.

Nonetheless, the *dependency* feature is invaluable and I would strongly recommend to experiment with it.

Comment: I think this is a great answer.  You may want to add a bit about NSOperationQueue (and `[NSOperationQueue -addOperationWithBlock:]`) which could simplify your approach.